# Prove that $d_X$ is a metric on $X$, where $X$ is the set of all closed subsets of the unit disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Tags: geometry, inequality, metric-spaces

Consider the closed unit disk $$D = \big\{(x, y) \in\mathbb{R}^2\,\big| x^2+y^2\leq 1\big\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$$ with
the metric $d$ induced from the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$, and let $X$ be the set of all closed
subsets of $D$. For $A\in X$ and $x \in D$, define
$$\text{dist}(x, A) := \min_{a\in A}\,
d(x, a)\,.$$
For $A, B \in X$, define
$$d_X(A, B) := \max
\left\{\max_{a\in A}\,\text{dist}(a, B),\max_{b\in B}
\text{dist}(b, A)\right\}\,.$$
Show that $d_X$ defines a metric on $X$.

How can I prove that $d_X$ satisfies the triangle inequality?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.**  For simplicity, I shall write $\delta$ for $\text{dist}$.  Note that, for $A,B,C\in X$, we have
$$\begin{align}d_X(A,B)&+d_X(B,C)\\&\geq \max\left\{{\small\max_{a\in A}\,\delta(a,B)+\max_{b\in B}\,\delta(b,C)}\,,\,\,{\small\max_{b\in B}\,\delta(A,b)+\max_{c\in C}\,\delta(B,c)}\right\}\,.\end{align}$$
Next, verify that
$$\max_{a\in A}\,\delta(a,B)+\max_{b\in B}\,\delta(b,C)\geq \max_{a\in A}\,\delta(a,C)$$
and that
$$\max_{b\in B}\,\delta(A,b)+\max_{c\in C}\,\delta(B,c)\geq \max_{c\in C}\,\delta(A,c)\,.$$
One probably important remark is that every set in $X$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.